# React-router-dom and history doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to import `react-router-dom` and `history` for work with React-router but doesn't work and I get this error.

[image]

I imported this packages:

- `yarn add react-router-dom`
- `yarn add history`

I'm working under `v14.4.0` version of node.

This is my code:

**index.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

const history = createHistory();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={history}>
    <App />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

**package.json** (for check a lot of versions xd):

````
{
  "name": "react-router",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "history": "^5.0.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}

```

If you need additional information for help me to solve the problem, don't doubt it for ask for.
Thanks a lot!!
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try importing it like this:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
const history = createBrowserHistory();
```